# Do we need to have app services having the same region as the vnet when we want to use services endpoints or private endpoints?

Tags: azure

I have a vnet in azure and some app services which are for now all share the same location, but in future I may be adding app services which haven't the same region as the vnet so I was wondering is this will make a problem if I want to connect to the vnet ( as they are not included in the vnet ) ?
I will be grateful for your explaination and your time

Answer (score 0):

I have never tried it, but according to this documentation, it should work to setup a private endpoint in a vnet in another region than the app service.

"You can also deploy the Private Endpoint in a different region than the Web App"

And

"You can enable multiple Private Endpoints in others VNets and Subnets, including VNets in other regions."

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/networking/private-endpoint#conceptual-overview

Comment: So it have to be a private endpoint not a service endpoint ?

Comment: I'm not sure about service endpoint, so therefore the answer was just about private endpoint.